# Swift Async call not updating data right away

Tags: swift, api

I am struggling to get the code below to work in my xcode project.
The first half of the code doesn't actually populate my code until around the cellforrowat function (not in the snippet below). Because of this the second half of the code snipit doesnt even run (because the movie array is still empty).
So I think my problem is that `DispatchQueue.main.async {self.tableView.reloadData()}` does not update my tableview right away.

```
var movies: [MovieDT] = []
var db: Firestore
var uid: String = ""

init(genre:Int, categoryNum:[Int], uid:String){
    db = Firestore.firestore()
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    
    self.uid = uid
    TMDBConfig.apikey = "xxx"
    
    GenresMDB.genre_movies(genreId: categoryNum[genre], include_adult_movies: true, language: "en") { [weak self] apiReturn, movieList in
        guard let self = self else {return}
        
        if let movies = movieList
        {
            for movie in movies
            {
                self.movies.append(MovieDT(title: movie.title ?? "Missing Title", description: movie.overview ?? " ", releaseDate: movie.release_date ?? " ", stars: movie.vote_average ?? 0, id: movie.id ?? 0))
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    //****************************************************************
    //code below does not work because the movies aren't generated yet
    //****************************************************************
    
    for movie in self.movies
    {
        self.db.collection("Movies").document(String(movie.id)).getDocument() { [weak self] (querySnapshot, err) in
        guard let self = self else {return}
            if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                    guard let snap = querySnapshot else {return}
                    let data = snap.data()
                    print(data?["upvoteCount"] as? Int ?? 0)
                    print(data?["downvoteCount"] as? Int ?? 0)
                    print("jhsjsj")
                }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: You’ve moved the code around, invalidating the answer below. Don’t retroactively change the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `GenresMDB.genre_moves` is an asynchronous function, the callback will execute on a separate thread. Meanwhile, `init` continues executing on the main thread. The API call takes time to complete, so your `for` loop executes before you've had a chance to update `movies`. If you add a `print` right after the guard and another one right before `for movie in self.movies`, I suspect you'll see the first print *after* the second one, even though you wrote the first one first.

So, the solution is just to move your for loop into the completion block. I would merge it with your `for movie in movies` loop. The trick is to make your code execute synchronously and deterministically, to ensure that it will certainly run in the order that you hope.

Comment: wooow that worked thanks man! I edited the code above. Is that how you were suggesting it? Thank you!!!

Comment: Yeah pretty much. For future readers of your question, revert your code to what it was originally and then add the working version below.

Comment: To make your code cleaner, you pretty much never want to nest two `DispatchQueue.main.async`s within each other. It's usually redundant. Also, you want to reload the `tableView` only *after* your for loop. It's poor for performance and potentially buggy to reload every iteration.

Comment: @raaamonnn - Don’t change the question. If you want, [post an answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), but don’t change it. Future readers are going to come here and wonder “what in the world are these guys talking about, as the code in the question should work fine?!?”

Comment: Sorry about changing my question into the answer thanks for reverting it! @Daniel cool thanks I will edit that.

Comment: I’m not sure why this is downvoted, as it’s basically right. I might have advised to pull all of this async code out of `init`, altogether, but the core issue has successfully been diagnosed, namely that the code dependent upon the async process must be placed in (or be called from) the completion handler of the async method.